# Ember-Data callback when findAll finished loading all records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With ember-data I'm loading all records of a model with:

```
App.adapter = DS.Adapter.create({
  findAll: function(store, type) {
      var url = type.url;
      jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {
          var ids = data.map(function(item, index, self){ return item.id });
          store.loadMany(type, ids, data);
      });
  }
});
```

The `didLoad` method is called when each of the record has finished loading. Is there a method to call when **all** records have finished loading?

---

EDIT

Model:

```
App.Article  = DS.Model.extend({

  title: DS.attr('string'),
  content: DS.attr('string'),


  checkIsLoaded: function() {
      if (this.get('isLoaded')){
         console.log('loaded!'); // outputs `loaded` for each record
      }
  }.observes('isLoaded')

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `findQuery`, and then observe `.isLoaded` property on the `ModelArray`.

e.g:

```
load: ->
    @set 'data', @get('store').findQuery App.MyModel, { q: '...' }
```

And have the observation:

```
loadingComplete: ( ->
    @doSomeStuff() if @getPath 'data.isLoaded'
).observes 'data.isLoaded'
```

Comment: Just tried it and it does the same: fires up on each record loaded

Comment: Absolutely, but in your code, each model instance observes the `isLoaded` property. In my proposition, the whole `ModelArray` is observed once, in usage context...

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that! It works as you suggest. Not sure why `findAll` doesn't set the `isLoaded` flag.

Comment: Well it's a question which was already raised in ember-data tracker... https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/83

Don't have any clue why... :-(

Comment: Whether one uses findAll or findQuery, the route is the same, so it doesn't require any change on the server end. And if you're using rails this will get routed to the index action and you can just ignore the query object and return all records.