# Wait for multiple models to load in an Ember View

Tags: canvas, ember.js

I have an Ember application that makes use of a canvas element. I'm using the following models:

A **Kit** hasMany **Positions** hasMany **Components** hasMany **Features**

Map route object that loads the model data for the first kit:

```
App.MapRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model : function() {
    return App.Kit.find(1);
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

And a canvas element view in this route

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars"  data-template-name="application">
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars"  data-template-name="map">
  {{view App.CanvasView }}
</script>
```

The canvas view:

```
App.CanvasView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'canvas',
  width: 600,
  height: 600,

  didInsertElement: function(){
   var el = this.$();

   // Pseudo Code
   // When all kit, Position, Component and Feature Data is loaded
   // Pass Data to createFabricCanvas
   // this.createFabricCanvas(el, data);

  },

  createFabricCanvas: function(el, data){
    fabCanvas = new fabCanvas(el, data);
  }
});
```

My question is how do I ensure all data for each of the hasMany models is loaded before it passes it into fabCanvas. The FabCanvas library is pre-written and assumes all data is available before processing.

I imagine the solution might involve checking the existence of each model with .on('didLoad').

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try to check and observe the `isLoaded` property on the parent model array like suggested in these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088094/in-ember-data-how-do-i-find-only-records-that-have-been-loaded) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031283/ember-data-callback-when-findall-finished-loading-all-records). Although I'm not sure if this guarantees that all the `has many` child relationship or your model are loaded aswell. But you could give it a try. I'll try to set up some tests for this use case on my own and update the answer if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In my case, my main model was a `App.Month`, and it `hasMany` `App.Company` models. This was a method in my view:

```
dataChanged: function() {
    if (this.get('controller.model.companies.isLoaded')) {
        Ember.run.once(this, 'someFunction');
    }
}.observes('controller.model.companies.isLoaded'),
```